# Get interpolated values in user defined 2D grid Paraview

Tags: paraview

I have a 2D flow and would like to obtain the value of certain scalar field in a set of points forming a regular mesh. These points should not coincide with the nodes of the actual mesh used in the CFD simulation.
May be you know how to automatize this process in ParaView.

Basicly, I need to first define the set of points, get the value of u at them, and save them in a matrix with x and y direction.

Cheers